# Code error - the future investment vlaue in Python

Tags: python, string, int, pow

I am begginer in python and this homework require me to get the future value of an investment.

```
p = raw_input("[How much did you invest?]:")
r = str(raw_input("[How much is the interest rate?]:"))
n = raw_input("[How long have you been investing?]:")
future_value = p*(1+1)**n
print "\n\n\tYour future value of your investment is: %s\n" % future_value
```

Error Code:

```
unsupported operand type(s) for ** or pow(): 'int' and 'str'
```

Any Help?

Answer (score 1):

You need to cast input to `int` because `raw_input` function returns a `string`

If you type `help(raw_input)` in interactive terminal, you should see the definition:

```
raw_input(...)
    raw_input([prompt]) -> string
```

Fixed code:

```
p = int(raw_input("[How much did you invest?]:"))
r = float(raw_input("[How much is the interest rate?]:"))
n = int (raw_input("[How long have you been investing?]:"))
future_value = p*(1+1)**n
print "\n\n\tYour future value of your investment is: %s\n" % future_value
```

Comment: It worked with (1+1)**n. When I changed it to (1+r)**2 I had the same error message.

Comment: In your original code, `r` was not used.  If you need to add `r` into the formula, you need to cast `r` to `int` as well :D Code above has been updated accordingly

Comment: [How much did you invest?]:1000
[How much is the interest rate?]:.08
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:\*\*\Desktop\CSC130-Assignment-2\Asn2-4.py", line 2, in <module>
    r = int(raw_input("[How much is the interest rate?]:"))
ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '.08'

Comment: This is what I had. And yes it was my mistake when i typed 1+1 instead of r :D

Comment: You need to cast it to `double` or `float` if you enter .08.  See my update

Comment: @Mingyu, `double()` isn't part of Python.  While Python floating-point numbers are C doubles, in Python it's spelled `float()`.

Answer (score 1):

The error message is telling you you're trying to raise integer to a string power.  That must be this part of the code:

```
(1+1)**n
```

Indeed, 1+1 is an integer (it's 2 - if 2 is what you want, why not write 2 instead of `1+1`?).

So what's `n`?  `n` was obtained from a `raw_input()` call.  And, indeed, `raw_input()` always returns a string.  If you want to change that string to an integer (you do), do this instead:

```
n = int(raw_input("[How long have you been investing?]:"))
```

Comment: Yes you are right actually .it is (1+r)**n. It was mistake when i typed 1+1. I still have the same error    unsupported operand type(s) for +: 'int' and 'str'

Comment: That's not the same error!  The first error you reported was about unsupported operands types for `**`.  Now you're getting one for `+`.  That's because `r` is a string:  **everything** returned by `raw_input()` is a string.  If you want `r` to be an integer, you need to add an `int()` call, same as before.  Or if you want `r` to be a floating-point number, a `float()` call.  I can't guess what you want ;-)

Comment: It worked when I used float() Thank you so much :)